# Why is my workflow not showing all the steps?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dynamics-crm-2011, workflow-foundation-4

I created a workflow in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 which I then exported and opened the XAML file with VS 2010. It shows me this when I open it:
[image]

But there are actually many more steps in this workflow. Why can't I see them or edit them? I tried clicking Expand All at the top right, but that didn't seem to make any difference. If I look at the actual code I can see the numerous steps - but no in the design view. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activities in your screenshot are custom activities. By default all you see is this placeholder. You can however create [custom activity designers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489419.aspx) and associate the activities with those. In your custom activity designer you can do anything you can do in WPF including showing the child activities.